# Chrome Extension activeTab Web Store Delay Publish

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm trying to publish my chrome extension but it's appears and i don't use permissions for active tab

> Because of the following issue, your extension may require an in-depth
>   review:
>   - Broad host permissions Instead of requesting broad host permissions, consider using the activeTab permission, or specify the sites that
>   your extension needs access to. Both options are more secure than
>   allowing full access to an indeterminate number of sites, and they may
>   help minimize review times.
>
> The activeTab permission allows access to a tab in response to an
>   explicit user gesture.
>
> { ... "permissions": ["activeTab"] } If your extension only needs to
>   run on certain sites, simply specify those sites in the extension
>   manifest: { ... "permissions": ["https://example.com/*"] }

My Manifest litterally don't have activeTab permissions

```
{
    "name" : "AZSolusindo VPN",
    "description" : "VPN Solusindo",
    "permissions" : [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "http://azsolusindo.info/*",
        "http://127.0.0.1/*"
    ],
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "browser_action" : {
        "default_icon": {
            "16" : "images/vpnoff.png",
            "32" : "images/vpn32.png",
            "48" : "images/vpn48.png",
            "128" : "images/vpn128.png"
        },
        "default_title": "AZ VPN",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "commands": {
        "_execute_browser_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+Shift+O",
                "mac": "Alt+Shift+O",
                "chromeos": "Alt+Shift+O",
                "linux": "Alt+Shift+O"
            },
            "description": "Open Pop Up."
        }
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
            "http://azsolusindo.info/vpn/index.php/template",
            "http://127.0.0.1/AzVPN/public/template"
            ],
        "js": ["JS/content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "version" : "0.9.5.1",
    "manifest_version" : 2
}
```

Is there anything i need to change ?

Comment: Make sure you understand the message correctly: it says 1) your extension is matching a very broad set of URLs (actually all URLs) so the review will take a lot of time and 2) the review process will be much faster if you can rewrite your extension so that it uses [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission or just a few URLs instead of all URLs.

Comment: Do you mean the content script matches ? or inside permission ?

Comment: It doesn't matter which because both produce the same final result. In your case it's "permissions".

Answer (score 2):

What’s getting flagged is your `<all_urls>` permissions entry. The message is saying that requesting such broad permissions is going to require a more in-depth review for your extension.

If you only need host permissions in a few places, then declare the specific hosts in your permissions array. As the message suggests, you can also use the `activeTab` permission if all you need is tab-related information and lifecycle events (such as tab id, URL, etc.).

If you do in fact potentially need full permissions on any given webpage, then there’s not much you can do here - your extension will need to go through the extended review.

Comment: hm... actually i make this for Web Proxy only some of website in my PAC Script, do i still need <all_urls> ?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by PAC Script, but you probably only need to declare permissions for those hosts where you want to be able to inject content scripts. As a start, try just removing the <all_urls> entry and see if things are still working.

Comment: i already got approved for all website with including some description